# Making AI Loop Properly?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm making an AI for a guessing game and I've run into an issue I can't seem to resolve on my own. The goal is to have the user input a number for the AI to guess within a reasonable amount of time, I'm generating a random number between 1-100 and running it through a loop to adjust lower or higher.

```
void AI::AIguess(int usernum)
{
        srand(time(NULL));
        AIchoice = rand() % High + Low;
    // "too high" or "too low" accordingly
    do {
        if (AIchoice == usernum)
        {
            cout << AIchoice << " is this correct?" << endl;
        }
        else if (AIchoice <= usernum)
        {
            cout << AIchoice << " seems a little low.." << endl;
            Low = AIchoice;
            AIchoice = 0;
            AIchoice = rand() % High + Low;
            AIguesses++;
        }
        else if (AIchoice >= usernum)
        {
            cout << AIchoice << " might have overshot a bit :/" << endl;
            High = AIchoice;
            AIchoice = 0;
            AIchoice = rand() % High + Low;
            AIguesses++;
        }
    } while (AIchoice != usernum);
}
```

I'm using the previous generated number to use as parameters for the next generated number, to hopefully get to the users number. It's bouncing between the if statements fine and adjusted the high and low respectively, but the problem I'm facing is after a few times through the loop AIchoice starts adding past 100. Anyone able to help me out?

P.S: Any helpful AI creating information is very appreciated :)

Comment: Just letting you know you don’t need to set AIChoice = 0 if you are going to assign it another value right after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your random number in an interval code is wrong. To generate a number between `min` and `max`, do `(rand() % (max - min)) + min`.

So change
`AIchoice = rand() % High + Low;`
to
`AIChoice = (rand() % (High - Low)) + Low;`.

Comment: Ah I understand where I went wrong, thanks a bunch :)

Comment: @rbrducky If the answer is correct please mark it as such :)

Comment: Do you possibly know a way to find the number faster? It can take between 2-13 tries and I'd like to make it consistently under 7.

Comment: @rbrducky You could try using some sort of weight (adding/subtracting/multipliying/dividing `High` or `Low` by some number every time you change it) or you could change the initial `High` or `Low` values to be closer to the user's inputted number. Otherwise it is kind of hard to do, as the main purpose of rand() is to be unpredictable